# Facebook - Make offline Graph API calls

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a task which I must make Graph API call in FQL to get how many friends of mine likes a specified page.

It looks like:

```
//Create Query
$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND page_id = $fbpageid"
);
//Run Query
$result = $facebook->api($params);
```

Now if user has 10 or 20 or 30 or 40 or 50 friends I have to warn him. I don't know the exact way, maybe post on his wall (Can you tell better?).

So can I do it by cron job since offline_access has been deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exchange the users access tokens with long-lived ones, which are valid for 30 days. If the user visits the app in these 30 days, you can extend the token for another 30.

How to exchange the access token is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/